# Comparing debt issuance across currencies

Tags: cross-currency-basis

Imagine I’m a European corporate thinking of issuing a bond in either GBP or EUR. I have the spread above gilts for a GBP transaction and a spread above mid swaps for EUR. How do I see which one would be more ‘cheaper’? I know I need to swap the GBP one to a EUR equivalent but how do I do that step by step?

Comment: I disagree on the closing of the question. It was not worded very clearly, but cross-currency comparisons are NOT "common knowledge". Just think that a library like QuantLib does not model it

Answer (score 3):

In order to determine which bond issuance would be cheaper, you would need to compare the all-in costs of each option. This involves taking into account the bond's yield and any associated currency swap costs. Here is a step-by-step guide:

1. Obtain the GBP bond's spread above gilts and the EUR bond's spread above mid-swaps.
2. Calculate the all-in yield for each bond by adding the respective spreads to the reference rates (i.e., gilts for GBP bond and mid-swaps for EUR bond).
3. Determine the GBP/EUR cross-currency basis swap rate. This rate represents the cost of swapping GBP cash flows to EUR cash flows, or vice versa, over the life of the bond.  The cross-currency basis swap rate can be calculated from the EUR swap rate, the GBP swap rate and the GBP/EUR cross-currency basis.
4. Convert the GBP bond's all-in yield to an equivalent EUR yield using the cross-currency basis swap rate. The formula to do this is:
   EUR-equivalent yield = GBP bond all-in yield - cross-currency basis swap rate
5. Compare the EUR-equivalent yield of the GBP bond to the all-in yield of the EUR bond. The bond with the lower all-in yield will be the cheaper option.

Keep in mind that this analysis assumes that your main concern is the cost of financing, and it does not consider other factors such as liquidity, investor base, and potential market risks.

Comment: In step 3 that rate is not directly observable.  It needs to be calculated from 3 observable: sterling swap rate, euro swap rate, and the sterling/euro cross currency basis.

Comment: Thank you dm63, I just checked Bloomberg again myself and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Out of interest, there are these cross-currency basis swaps on Bloomberg (e.g. ADBSX1 Curncy), but when looking at them, there is no data available. Would you know why brokers are not providing quotes for these?

Comment: A lot of the bberg tickers have changed due to the transition away from Libor.  Look at ADBSQQ1

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the question fully. Do you mean that you can choose between issuing a bond in GBP and one in EUR, and you want to calculate which is cheaper?

**One way to think about it is to price a xccy (cross-currency) swap.
This way you can calculate that, for a certain tenor and certain characteristics, a bond paying Euribor + 400 swaps to, say, GBP Sonia + 440. People typically refer to this saying there is a 40-bp pickup from GBP to EUR.**

So if, for whatever reason (e.g. the investor base being much larger in one currency than another, different appetite, etc) you can place your EUR bonds at Euribor + 400, but you can place your GBP bonds at Sonia + 450, it would be "cheaper" to issue in EUR, because GBP S + 450 swaps to Euribor + 410, which is more than Euribor + 400

A few clarifications:

- this comparison looks at just the cost of financing; it ignores other factors like liquidity, the counterparty risk from the swap, the different legal and regulatory framework of issuing in one currency vs another, etc.
- if the cashflows are certain, the comparison holds. The more elements of uncertainty there are, the harder it is to price the xccy, and the greater the chances that you may end up over-hedged or under-hedged. E.g. if the bond is callable, if the cashflows are uncertain (like in many ABS/RMBS bonds, where it's hard to forecast the exact amortisation), if partial prepayments are allowed under certain conditions, etc. What I mean is that the xccy pickup for a 5-year bond may be 20 bps, but maybe it is closer to zero for a shorter bond, so if you call it or prepay a lot the economics will be different.
- there are some complications when comparing a daily rate like Sonia to a non-daily rate like Euribor

**Do you have access to Bloomberg?** If you do, you can price a xccy swap with SWPM, specifically `SWPM -FLFL` for floating to floating, and `SWPM -FXFX` for fixed to fixed. Remember to set premium to zero and to solve for the spread.

**If you price a xccy swap, the 3 main curves which affect the result are:**

- the GBP reset rate
- the EUR reset rate
- the FWD fx

In the case of floating to floating, what does it mean that EUR + 400 swaps to GBP + 440?
Well, for each payment date:

1. The GBP leg receives reset rate + 440
2. The EUR leg pays reset rate + 400
3. The net payment in GBP =1-2 converted into GBP at the forward FX of the payment date

**The two legs are equivalent because:**

- if you take the EUR payment at 2,
- convert it into GBP at the forward rate of the date,
- then discount it using the GBP discount curve,
- the present values of the two legs are the same